# How to delete project in django

Tags: python, django, project

Initially, I had a single project in Django now I want to delete the last project and start a fresh new project with the same name as the last one. How should I do so? Can deleting the project folders be sufficient.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Deleting the project folder is sufficient and make changes in your apache server too[if you have one].

Comment: I would'nt delete it. I normally create a folder called "backup" or "old" and move the old project there. Just to be on the save side.

Comment: Ideally you are using a revision control :)

Answer (score 6):

To delete the project you can delete the project folder.
But this method is good only if you use SQLite as a database.

If you use any other database like Postgresql with Django, you need to delete the database manually.

If you are on VPS. Simply go to the folder where your project folder resides and put command `rm -r projectfoldername`

This should delete the folder and it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

As @Neverbackdown said deleting folder would be sufficient, but along with that you would also want to delete database or tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Just Delete the folder. If the project is installed in your settings.py, remove it.